# Catching a DLL crash in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, dll, crash

I'm calling a function from a DLL, like this:

```
__declspec ( dllimport ) bool dll_function(...);

int main() {
  [...]
  if (dll_function(...)) {
    [...]
  }
}
```

In some cases, the data I pass to the DLL function will lead to a crash of the DLL. Is it possible to catch this so my application doesn't crash as well (without modifying the DLL which is not created by me)?

Comment: does the dll throw an exception? or is it a bug?

Comment: The DLL doesn't throw an exception, I guess it tries to access invalid memory, Windows gives a typical error dialog and after that, my application won't continue running.

Comment: @GMan: I don't have access to the DLL sources and can't modify the DLL. I just want to know if there's some `try...catch` way to prevent my application from crashing.

Comment: It's almost impossible to fix this without knowing the source of the function. If that's not the case, you better hope it's well-documented and that you can figure out what you're doing with it that the documentation doesn't allow.

Comment: If the DLL is hard-crashing, then you don't *want* to try and carry on. You have *no idea* what it's done and what memory it's scribbled over.

Comment: @Anon: Ah, good argument. Would it help to call the function in a seperate thread in this case?

Comment: @schnaader: No, that wouldn't help. You'd need to spawn a separate process for it if you wanted any guarantee that it's not going to corrupt your own data structures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can catch AVs with the __try and __except keywords in the MSVC compiler.  Not all that useful, you have no idea what kind of damage was done.  The state of your program might well be corrupted.  The heap might be blown for example, causing subsequent random failure.  Hosting the DLL in its own process and using IPC to talk to it is the only decent approach.

Answer (score 2):

> In some cases, the data I pass to the
>   DLL function will lead to a crash of
>   the DLL. Is it possible to catch this
>   so my application doesn't crash as
>   well?

Isn't it possible to prevent the dll from crashing if you only call the function with valid data? That should be the preferable solution in any case - but its hard to tell without knowing which dll you want to use. But in most cases, you should have an idea what "data" exactly results in an crash...

Comment: OK, some more details: This is for my program Precomp (http://schnaader.info/precomp.php) The function I call is a JPG recompression function of PackJPG (http://www.elektronik.htw-aalen.de/packjpg/). There are (invalid) JPGs that make PackJPG crash and to prevent this, I'd have to improve my JPG detection/parsing which I think is much more effort than just catching and handling the crash (if this is possible at all, of course).

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680634%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

and

Enforce Filter code by Oleg Starodumov (www.debuginfo.com)

http://www.debuginfo.com/articles/debugfilters.html

However, that is a top level filter and not a try/catch.  You can perhaps restart your process.

You might need to use __try for exceptions.  Again, probably better to fix the problem or just crash than to try to catch it.
I agree with the others that rather than suppressing or hiding the crash you should fix it.  I don't know how well you can recover from the crash - is it going to be useful to continue execution after something like that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the problem, try specifying the correct calling convention. (`__stdcall`, `__cdecl`, etc).

If that's not the problem, we need to see what you are passing to the function and possibly the function code if you have it.

Comment: The calls should be fine, most of the time this works, I even have a standalone executable version of the DLL function that also crashes on the invalid input data. I'm sure I won't be able to fix the crash, just want to know how to handle it.