# Handling plug ins in c

Tags: c++, c, dll, plugins, segmentation-fault

I am making a small game engine that uses dynamic code reloading. The update function is provided by a dll. Whenever a new dll is found, it is loaded along with the new update function. The issue is that memory errors can still happen so a segfault takes down the entire engine. I'm asking if there's a way I can handle such cases and close the dll etc to recover from it. I know that plug ins solve this issue by running in a separate process but I'd rather not do that if possible.

Comment: Did you know that C and C++ engineers fight in bars?  You should tag questions with both languages very carefully...  (please update your question with just the language that you're using)

Comment: `segfaults` are not recoverable. At best you can only make a crash dump and fix code that caused them.

Comment: Sandboxing using processes is really the only way to recover from a crash.

Comment: Well in Windows you can catch access violations (aka segfaults) but the usefulness of that is very limited; when it happens, you can't be sure your memory hasn't been corrupted and there will most certainly be (massive) resource leaks. Use isolated components (processes with IPC e.g. COM) instead.

Comment: I believe the obvious answer here would be that you should carefully chose **which** dlls you are loading, before the result is a segfault. Also, exception handling might help here, although it is not panacea.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Catching a DLL crash in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939861/catching-a-dll-crash-in-c-c)

Comment: You can catch segfault with Structure Exception Handling and check that it caused by some code trying to access old dll address. The problem is there's not much you can do after that.

Comment: @UKMonkey , C/C++ have very much the same feature set when it comes to tackling this problem. The issue you raised is really just pedantic.

Comment: @Temp4890 They suffer the same problem, but then you could've tagged java, C#, python and bash under the same argument.   They do not have the same tool sets to tackle this problem, which is why the answer is so vague.  Had you been more specific people may have been able to point you to more specific and useful information.

Comment: @UKMonkey they literally have the same tool set to tackle this specific problem. I tagged it as such c and c++ because I don't want comments asking why not launch an interpreter for x scripting language instead. Heck, this is more of a os level question than a language level one. If tagging is really the issue here then c and c++ tags shouldn't even be there. That is if you really want to be pedantic about this.

Comment: @Temp4890 I didn't realize that C could deal with classes and had boost.

Comment: @UKMonkey and how do either of those things answer my question. I'm asking for an os level question. The language tags are to give context on the level I'm working at. I'm less interested in whatever flowery abstractions and libraries that do this than if it's even possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, no.

Assuming you're using the traditional `LoadLibrary` method of run-time DLL importing or equivalent, the DLL is explicitly imported into the [address space of the calling process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx). The DLL code has as much access to the host application's memory as the host application itself does, so even before it crashes it can destroy the state of the host application. The only thing you can do is crash and take out the whole process.

To protect the host application, you'll have to bite the bullet and load the library in a subprocess or sandbox. Otherwise you're implicitly trusting the DLL to do the right thing.

Incidentally, this is pretty well answered already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939861/catching-a-dll-crash-in-c-c).

Comment: I kind of expected as much. It'd be nice if the OS supported such a feature though. Thanks for clarifying.